# There's a strlen, and a wcslen, but is there a template function like strlen<char> or strlen<wchar_t>?

Tags: c++

There's a strlen, and a wcslen function, but is there a templated character array length function so you can do something like `strlen<char>` or `strlen<wchar_t>`?

If not, then I guess I'll write my own.

Comment: if you are working under Windows, there is the whole lot of _tcs* functions, but it's something different (and in 2011 you shouldn't still program for the Ansi charset in Windows)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just write your own ambiguous overload for this?

Comment: @Daniel Turns out I don't need to write an overload, just look at the answer below. I just wanted to use the standard if it existed, and in the process I found out about the char_traits features; if I went with what you said I wouldn't have learned anything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have the char_traits helper used by std::string.

It provides `char_traits<char>::length` and `char_traits<wchar_t>::length`.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using templates wouldn't you be using std::string (which is of course templated) ?

Comment: Thanks for not answering my question. No, this is for writing to a basic_ofstream<CharType> and allowing a person to pass in a character array buffer.

Comment: @leetNightshade - that's the reason that there isn't a common templated C string std library but feel free to write your own

Comment: In that case, you're required (I think) to use the corresponding function in the traits class.

Comment: I already have it setup in my Engine to allow someone to write a basic_string<CharType>, however if they want to pass in a buffer, perhaps created from a Network connection, then I want to have that option instead of creating a string then writing to a file.

Comment: @James Kanze Wait, corresponding traits class? char_traits? What do you mean?

Comment: @leetNightshade - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319770/what-is-the-point-of-stl-character-traits although it's not really relevent

Comment: All of the class templates in iostream take two template arguments, the
charT and a traits.  The traits defaults to char_traits<charT>, but
using this for anything but char or wchar_t is undefined behavior.  So
someone has to provide one.  According to the definitions in table 37.
And all of the iostream classes will use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T> size_t strlen( T * _arg )
{
  if ( _arg == 0 )
    return -1;
  size_t i = 0;
  while ( _arg[i] != 0 ) ++i;
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Would you not want to use template specialization to call the standard version which may have been specially optimized (almost forgot what about multi-word representations are you sure the terminating character is always '\0' on wchar_t (ie could it be in the middle of a triplet)? (I am not)).

Comment: @Martin: if you store your string in `vector` for any reason, you may need this function. Of course `find` may be good, too.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be std::find, with a special end iterator that
never matches anything.  (In a template, you're looking for T().)

Answer (score 0):

No.

This is because strlen() and wcslen() are part of C (not C++) and thus handle C-Strings.

C++ discourages the use of C-Strings by providing std::string (std::wstring). These are of course templates of (std::basic_string<T>).

Rather than write your own would it not be better to shift to C++ std::string?

Comment: Again, this is being used inside of a IWriteFile which allows you to write a basic_string<CharType>, a CharType*, or a void* with size. So I need this for the second option if I don't want to spend the time creating a string from the buffer. For example, the buffer could've been created from a Network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious way is to have your function take a `basic_string<CharType>` and let the user form one of those. Then all the length stuff is hidden away in the standard library.

If that's not suitable, just keep a running track of the character count as you're copying them into the stream's internal buffer.