# any way to read in and make lower case in same step?

Tags: c++, cin, lowercase, tolower

I'm reading in user input via

```
string word;
while(cin >> myWord)
    //put myWord in array
```

but for the sake of sorting I want "This" and "this" to be the same. For my sort algorithm I'm using the default < and > values for string, so This != this, and for my purposes I need it to == so I want to just immediately make everything lowercase while it's read in. From the tolower I see I would need to make a `for` loop to iterate through word and make it lowercase, so I'd need to do this inside of the while loop before putting the word into the array. But I'm wondering if there's any trick I can do to make put the word from cin into `myWord` already lower case (or make "myWord" lower case right after being read in) in one line, along the lines of `cin >> myWord.lower` is what I'm talking about

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert std::string to lower case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case)

Comment: I'm not sure about how to do it in the same step but you could call [tolower](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/tolower.html) before putting it in the array to make sure it is lowercase.

Comment: I would change the sorting order in `std::sort` via a custom `SortPredicate` that compares strings ignoring the case.

Comment: Run your input through a preprocessor: `tr A-Z a-z | my-program`

Comment: @TommyK Add the word as-is and not change the case.  When you call `std::sort`, that is where you compare without case.

Comment: Tommy, I think it's a bit unclear, are you trying to sort string, or the vector of strings?

Comment: Or just change sorting order but keep the caseness of the strings ?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it, by using a custom sorting predicate for `std::string`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

struct SortNoCase // functor used to sort strings ignoring the case
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
    {
        std::string lhs_lower, rhs_lower;
        std::transform(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), 
            std::back_inserter(lhs_lower), ::tolower);
        std::transform(std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs), 
            std::back_inserter(rhs_lower), ::tolower);
        return lhs_lower < rhs_lower;
    }
};


int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vs{"Some", "strings", "THAT", "are", "UnSorted"};

    std::sort(std::begin(vs), std::end(vs), SortNoCase());

    for(auto&& elem: vs)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

PS: there are more sophisticated approaches, like using custom char traits, but this does it and it's easy to understand. If you're really curios, can take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319855/3093378

Answer (score 0):

```
std::for_each(myWord.begin(),myWord.end(),[] (char &c) {c=std::tolower(c);});
```

Comment: If that's what the OP needs, it works perfectly, although I had the impression he wants to sort the array of strings ignoring the case.

Comment: @vsoftco I found it a bit confusing too. He wrote he wants instant transformation to lower case. And this one liner is very instant I hope. In case he wants to preserve caseness and only changes sorting order he definitely should go with your costum comparator.